# what are some good 3rd party tools you have found useful in ios development?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Specifically looking for 3rd party tools free/commercial that have reduced development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use phonegap,titanium etc if u google as cross platform mobile..but it wont help much to you to give correct output..if u learn each technology, it will be better...see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380196/cross-platform-development-for-mobile-devices)